# Compile XPCOM idl file using 64bit Ubunty based system

Tags: firefox, xpcom, gecko, geckosdk

I'm working on a XPCOM interface for Firefox. To compile my .idl file using 64-bit Ubuntu based system, I couldn't find the specific Gecko SDK version. I tired to download "Linux x86_64" version of Gecko SDK from [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_SDK) in which I couldn't find "xpidl" file inside bin folder. This is the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript#Using_XPCOMUtils) I followed. It would be great to hear where I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The build system uses new xpidl written in python since quite some time.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPIDL/pyxpidl